# d3.js how to dynamically add only those nodes to collapsible tree, selected from a datatable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working on collapsible tree in which a large set of data overlapping occurs and the whole tree looks clumsy.
What I am trying to do is to open a data-table and expand only selected nodes from the data-table something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqXBP.png), on selecting MN type node, a data-table opens [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDBtz.png) and on selecting any of up to 5 nodes using checkbox,all the 5 nodes shall be expanded to that parent MN node like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by0rx.png) but it does not expand here.

This is what I have tried so far

```
var selected;  //select node to which data shall be expanded
var selectedMnDataArray =[]; //collecting data from data-table
selectedMnDataArray.parent = selected; 

if(!selected.children){
                selected.children = [];
                selected.treeData5.children = [];
              }
              selected.children.push(selectedMnDataArray);
              selected.treeData5.children.push(selectedMnDataArray.data);

              update(selected);
```

But this only expands a link as you can see in the picture.

Another thing I tried is from the post [d3.js how to dynamically add nodes to a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589308/d3-js-how-to-dynamically-add-nodes-to-a-tree)

But this also doesn't work in my case.

please anyone help me out here.

Comment: `var selectedMnDataArray =[];` this will define this variable as an Array. But later you typed `selectedMnDataArray.parent = selected` which overwrites the first statement turning the array into a JSON object.

Comment: yeah that is the point as I am collecting data from data-table as an array of objects, which shall be expanded next and selectedMnDataArray.parent = selected is marking that nodes inside array shall be children to which parent.